# Convert sql output to string in python

Tags: python, mysql

I am quite new to coding (I actually started 3 days ago), so please bare with me in case this question is easy to solve.

Here is my problem:

1. I connected myself to my db and requested data from db using `mysql.connector` in PyCharm
2. I want the result to be a plain string and assign this "plain" data to a variable so I can use it later in my code
3. I do get the result in a different way (is it a list?)

So here is my code:

```
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("select firstname from customer c join application a on a.customerid = c.id where c.id=1;")
firstname = mycursor.fetchall()

print(firstname)
```

My current output:

```
[('Max',)]
```

My expected output:

```
Max
```

Any ideas how I can convert `firstname` to my desired format?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: hi, perhaps get the first row with `fetchone` and then get the first column with `row[0]`

Comment: thanks for the answer, I only get one value (=firstname), I was wondering how I can remove these characters right and left `[('',)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need a single row, use `mycursor.fetchone()` instead of `mycursor.fetchall()`.

The result you're currently getting is a list containing 1 tuple containining 1 string. It can be accessed as `firstname = mycursor.fetchall()[0][0]`

The better solution is `firstname = mycursor.fetchone()[0]`

Comment: Thanks, also for the explanation. Will do some research on this "tuple" thingy.

Answer (score 0):

mycursor = mydb.cursor()
Var1 =[]
mycursor.execute("select firstname from customer c join application a on a.customerid = c.id where c.id=1;")
firstname = mycursor.fetchall()
for nameList in firstname:

```
  nameList.append(firstname)
```

print(nameList)

Try this...